# How can I enable software rendering when building xcframework with Flutter for iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, xcframework

Can I force software rendering when building xcframework with flutter?

Is it possible to have something like:

```
flutter build ios --enable-software-rendering
```

similar to

```
flutter run ios --enable-software-rendering
```

I want to know if it possible to enable it inside the code, or it can be added anywhere to run?